# In-app-purchase - LoadListingInformationAsync() doesnt work WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create In-app-purchase in my WP 8.1 app, but i have problem with displaying all the in-app products available for purchase. I can not load listing information

I have this code, but when I try to load products, my application crashes on line `var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();`

```
 var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
foreach (var product in listing.ProductListings)
{
  sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2},{3}, {4}",
    product.Key,
    product.Value.Name,
    product.Value.FormattedPrice,
    product.Value.ProductType,
    product.Value.Description));
}
 MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog(sb.ToString(),"asd");
    await msg.ShowAsync();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [CurrentAppSimulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.aspx) while developing the app and change the code while pushing into the store.

Comment: So this code is working only when app is available on the store ?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yes, the code will work when published to the store.
@EgorN Thank you for informing, Will take care next time :)